# Test that a table exists in Luasqlite

Tags: sqlite, lua

I'm using [Luasqlite](http://luasqlite.luaforge.net/lsqlite3.html).

If I wanted to write a test to verify that a table exists, that returns boolean, how would I go about doing it?

It seems if I try selecting something from a table that doesn't exist, as my test, then the application errors out altogether.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also query the table `sqlite_master` to look for your table, eg:

```
found=false
db:exec([[select * from sqlite_master where name='my_table';]],
function(...) print(...) found=true return 0 end)
if found then print'table exists!' end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the 'table_info' pragma.

```
db:exec("pragma table_info('Publication');") --check for table 'Publication'
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm not able to get the solution working with your code as of yet though. print()'ing the statement outputs 0 whether the table name I've entered exists as a table or not.

Comment: Does `pragma table_info('tablename');` work from your Sqlite3 shell?